# How can i put my credentials in an batch file with powershell scripting in it

Tags: powershell

```
@ECHO OFF
echo start powershell

call powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "$null=Install-Script -Name Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo -force"

call powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "& $env:ProgramFiles\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo.ps1 -online
```

This is the `.bat` file. At the `Get-Windowsautopilotinfo.ps1 -online` I am asked to enter my credentials twice. Can I automate this process?

Comment: Why do you create a batch file in the first place and not use a `.ps1` file? Otherwise, there is the `CredentialManager` library which may help you.

Comment: Do you have a `get-credential` command somewhere in your Get-WindowsAutoPilotInfo.ps1 ?

Comment: @PowerCat no i don't have an get-credential command in my .ps1

Comment: Problem with the get-credential is that its an new laptop/workstation. I want to start an powershell or .bat from an USB. and if possible by a user (without rights)

Comment: Maybe you're asked to enter credential from UAC which is not script related